# Describing the boundary of a region - Vector Calculus

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, vector-analysis

Let $E$ (in three dimensional real space) be a surface parametrised by $\underline p:R\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$, where $R=\{(\theta,\phi):0\le\theta\le\pi, 0\le\phi\le\frac{\pi}{2}\}$, and $\underline p(\theta,\phi)=(\sin\theta \cos\phi,\sin\theta \sin\phi, \cos\theta)$.

Describe the boundary $\partial E$. I don't know how to do this - would we simply substitute in $\theta=\pi, \phi=\frac{\pi}{2}$ to our expression for $\underline p$? Wouldn't this only give a single point?

Comment: Did you graph the function? Try fixing either $\theta$ or $\phi$ and letting the other vary. What does that tell you about the boundary?

Comment: At $\phi = 0$, $ r(\theta) = (\sin\theta, 0, \cos\theta), 0 \leq \theta \leq \pi$ is part of the boundary... similarly at $\phi = \frac{\pi}{2}$, find the boundary

Comment: @CyclotomicField sorry I'm really confused...

Comment: @MathLover I don't understand what you mean, could you explain please?